# how to convert digits to ascii value or characters and store in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I am trying to generate a prime key from a phone number provided by the users on my application.

for example, user provides following phone number:

> Phone number: 033232532523

Now, I want to generate some kind of key like converting those digits to alphabet, special characters or ascii value or kind of that, so that I could get a key something like this (dummy):

> ab743kdhad$

e.g replacing 0 with a, getting ascii value of 3 and so on...

The code I am trying to get is something like this:

public class PrimeKeyGenerator {

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    String phoneNumber = "123456342";

    //could we convert the digits to characters or replace the digits with their ascii value?
    String characters = convertNumToCharacters( phoneNumber );

    System.out.println( "Generated Prime Key: " + characters );


}

private static String convertNumToCharacters(String phoneNumber) {

    return null;

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the digits to a `byte[]` and then apply a `SHA-1` hash and then Base64 encode the result. Something like,

```
private static String convertNumToCharacters(String phoneNumber) {
    byte[] digits = new byte[phoneNumber.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        digits[i] = (byte) Character.digit(phoneNumber.charAt(i), 10);
    }
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(md.digest(digits));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which returns (with your input `"123456342"`)

```
Generated Prime Key: wlwRLSZuhzMBn5Yw6RVfw+dwegM=
```

and (with my phone #)

```
Generated Prime Key: botMioqy/9B4tu/KvLv5Cc/Ykak=
```

Comment: please tell me which package do I import Base64? @Elliott

Comment: please tell me about Base64 where do I bring/import it from?

Comment: [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) is the one I used here.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me the way I needed.

Comment: for Base64, I replaced the return statement with this one

**         return Base64.encode(md.digest(digits));
**